# How can I delete a specific line (e.g. line 102,206,973) from a 30gb csv file?

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, csv, import

What method can I use to delete a specific line from a csv/txt file that is too big too load into memory and edit manually?

**Background**

My question is actually an indirect solution to a problem related with importing csv into sql databases.

I have a series of 10-30gb csv files I want to import and populate an sqlite table from within R (Since they are too large to import as data frames as a whole into R). I am using the 'RSQlite' package for this.

A couple fail because of an error related to one of the lines being badly formatted. The populating process is then cancelled. R returns the line number which caused the process to fail.

The error given is:

```
./csvfilename line 102206973 expected 9 columns of data but found 3)
```

So I know exactly the line which causes the error.

I see 2 potential 'indirect' solutions which I was hoping someone could help me with.

(i) Deleting the line causing the error in 20+gb files. e.g. line 102,206,973 in the example above.
I am not concerned with 'losing' the data in line 102,206,973 by just skipping or deleting it. However I have tried and failed to somehow access the csv file and to remove the line.

(ii) Using sqlite directly (or anything else?) to import an csv which does allow you to skip lines or an error.

Although not likely to be related directly to the solution, here is the R code used.

```
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname=name_of_table)
dbWriteTable(conn = db, name ="currentdata", value = csvfilename, row.names = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To delete a specific line you can use `sed`:

```
sed -e '102206973d' your_file
```

If you want the replacement to be done in-place, do

```
sed -i.bak -e '102206973d' your_file
```

This will create a backup names `your_file.bak` and `your_file` will have the specified line removed.

#### Example

```
$ cat a
1
2
3
4
5
$ sed -i.bak -e '3d' a
$ cat a
1
2
4
5
$ cat a.bak 
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Which language is this? How could I run this? Thanks!

Comment: Commandline in Linux. If you are running Windows you'll have a problem to execute it...

Comment: @Hugstime `sed` is a UNIX utility. You can use it directly from your console. You can also use it in Windows with cygwin.

Comment: Ah ok I have cygwin installed. Will give it a try. Is there any preceding code I need to run?

Comment: No, @Hugstime, just `sed ...` will make it. As I see you accepted the answer it means you could do it perfectly. Great!